# How do I install Brother MFC7340 - Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: printing

I have  a Brother MFC7340 which I have installed, but it doesn't respond and when it did it just spitted out blank pages. Can anyone help please and relatively new to Ubuntu. I have Ubuntu 12.10 on dual with Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this printer via Network or USB and is your Ubuntu 32bit or 64bit? I also had troubles with my Brother printer the first time I installed it.

Comment: I am using vis USB and its Ubuntu 32bit..

Answer (score 0):

Is it really 3740, I couldn't find a reference to that printer anywhere? I don't have this printer (or any Brother for that matter) but found a few interesting links.

An article about Brother releasing Linux drivers
http://voices.yahoo.com/the-retail-detail-brother-releases-drivers-installer-7131276.html

A list of supported printer with instructions and driver downloads
http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html

The Brother Linux printer FAQ
http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/faq_prn.html

I have found that often if my exact printer isn't on a list that one similar will work, I have also seen that within a specific driver during setup (or changing the properties) the particular method of printing can be changed to get things running.  I usually try the recommended method at the top of the list first but have at least one printer that worked much better by selecting a different method.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I have tried using another model's drivers, but it pulls paper through without printing anything.

Comment: So it is the 7340 drivers from the Brother website that don't work?